# Blackberry XMPP messages

Tags: blackberry, java-me, xmpp

Made an Blackberry application with XMPP backed for receiving real-time messages for the users, expected to give a feel like push message to the top business users for some key events happens in desktop ERP system by the endusers.

Ok let me go to my doubt..

1. Sockettimeout, max is 2 mins..handled by listening for the connection failure and getting reconnected..will this cause high CPU usage?
2. Listening for xmpp messages with idling socket connection...will this cause high CPU usage..in-turn high battery consumption and any performance degradation..
3. Do we have any tool to identify the CPU and battery consumption by the APP on device or  simulator?

Please help me out...

Rgds
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to get some clue of CPU usage of my app through BB Simulator ported on 6.0 OS, clearly its show the CPU usage during the application activities.

In OS 6.0 you can findout this option under Options -> Device -> Application Management.

1. During idling socket connection 0% CPU consumption.
2. When a message arrives through XMPP socket consumption goes upto less than 1 to 1% CPU.
3. During reconnection after socket timeout consumption takes standard of 7% CPU.

On the average very less consumption, hope my apps wont drain my customers batter :).

Hope this detail will help others in the app performance point of view.